# how to remove Cocoapods on mac

Tags: ruby, macos

When I run flutter doctor (MacOS Sonoma), it tells me `cocoapods` is installed:

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
      To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

But when I try to remove it:

```
george@mycomputer % sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
george@mycomputer % sudo gem uninstall -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
george@mycomputer ~ % brew uninstall cocoapods
Error: Cask 'cocoapods' is not installed.
```

Where/how else could cocoapods be, and how to remove it?

Answer (score 4):

I found similar issues with cocoapods on the latest OS Sonoma when attempting to update to the newest version of cocoapods, using RubyGems.

What worked for me was using homebrew CLI.

https://brew.sh/

Install homebrew and run the following command

**brew uninstall cocoapods**

Then remove any references to cocoapods in your home folder

**rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/**